# What is "this.return" in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

While in VS Code, I hit the tab after typing return and the VS Code Intellisense auto-completed "return" to "this.return".

I've never seen this before and cannot find any documentation on it.

Does anybody know if this is actually a thing, or if VS Code possibly lost it's marbles.

Note: the object I was working in does not have any properties or functions called "return".

Comment: Impossible to know without knowing what `this` might be. If it happens to be a generator, then [there is a `.return()` method on them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator/return) but than that? Who knows. It would be pure guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

Well, an object *could* have a property called return:

```
const obj = {
  return: () => { console.log('↩️'); }
};

obj.return();
```

Were you in the context of a class that had a `return` property, or maybe its superclass did?

(Honestly it seems more likely VS Code was just being weird.)

Answer (score 0):

You can run `console.log("this", this)` in most modern browsers this will return the `JSON` data of `this` (the variable `this` refers to the current instance of declared `object` FYI), and `console.log(typeof(this.return))` and it will likely return `function` (if you get `undefined` just change it from `this.return` to `return;`)

Likely the object either has a property called `return` that is a `function`, or something has gone wrong in the autocomplete.